# How to combine array results in php in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Please read all the description carefully before commenting, I am newbie.

Following is my PHP code

```
foreach ($mycatarr as $mycat)
{
   $all_posts = all_posts_list($mycat);
}
```

Now the problem is **all_posts_list($mycat)** returns the value in array.
I want to combine all the results that generated by foreach loop.

*Note that here I don't want to store these results in another array.

**Array Structure**

```
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'pid' => string '3' (length=1)
      'userid' => string '6' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'http://buzzlink.local/terms-and-service' (length=39)
      'title' => string 'This is just a test title of the content' (length=40)
      'description' => string 'This is just a normal text description and I am enjoying it while typing in this kind of things as i
' (length=101)
      'credits' => string '20' (length=2)
      'categories' => string '10' (length=2)
      'status' => string '1' (length=1)
      'addtime' => string '1454391098' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      'pid' => string '16' (length=2)
      'userid' => string '6' (length=1)
      'url' => string 'http://buzzlink.local/terms-and-service' (length=39)
      'title' => string 'This is just a test title of the content' (length=40)
      'description' => string 'This is just a normal text description and I am enjoying it while typing in this kind of things as it helps me to speed up my typing and blah blah blah as this is just a test thing and description.' (length=197)
      'credits' => string '20' (length=2)
      'categories' => string '10' (length=2)
      'status' => string '1' (length=1)
      'addtime' => string '1454391098' (length=10)
```

Comment: here all_posts_list($mycat) generates same structures array for different category values, I just want to combine the result.

Comment: Post some example array structure with expected output better to provide better code

Comment: @SarvagnaMehta, combine into what??? into array or concatenate values to single string?

Comment: dump the output of all_posts_list($mycat) so we can see what its structure looks like

Comment: checkout the structure that I added above

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$result=[];
foreach ($mycatarr as $mycat){
  $result = array_merge($result, $mycat);
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: getting following error `array_merge(): Argument #2 must be of type array,`

Answer (score 0):

use array_merge : https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php

```
foreach ($mycatarr as $mycat)
{
   $all_posts = array_merge($all_posts, all_posts_list($mycat));
}
```

Comment: Not working. Note that $all_posts is normal variable, its not an array.

Comment: please paste the array-structure you get from all_posts_list and the array-structure you want to get

Comment: I edited that array structure, please have a look at the question.